# AjaxFileUpload output message back from php

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function ajaxFileUpload(){
    $.ajaxFileUpload({
            url:'upload.php', 
            secureuri:false,
            fileElementId:'fileToUpload',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data, status){
                if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined'){
                    if(data.error != ''){
                        alert(data.error);
                    }else{
                        alert(data.msg);
                    }
                }
            },
            error:function(data, status, e){
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    )

    return false;
}
```

I have a file upload use ajaxFileUpload plugin. it send the file to upload.php

php will check everything, if correct it will save the file in server.

if there are any problem found from php, php will echo out the problem and send message back.

My question is how to output message back from php?

ex. if php find out the file format is in jpg/jpeg, than php file will echo "file must be jpg/jpeg"

Comment: what do you have in upload.php?

Comment: if(isset($_FILES['image'])){echo "ok";} this is just for testing, in my php file i check many thing (exif_imagetype, imagecreatefromjpeg...)

Comment: is it json encoded? the response of your php file has to be in JSON format, so put `header('Content-type: application/json');` and convert your response to a json encoded array like `echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'ok'))`